# React Native Maps onMapReady getMapBoundaries

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I haven't been able to find anything to fix it. I'm using react-native maps

```js
const finalMap = () => {

    return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.authContainerStyles}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        region={{
          latitude:   !!userLocation ? userLocation.coords.latitude : 43.60271848664041,
          longitude: !!userLocation
          ? userLocation.coords.longitude
          : -116.20149258821509,
          latitudeDelta: 0.05,
          longitudeDelta: 0.05,
        }}
        onMapReady = {this.map.getMapBoundaries()}
      >
```

Comment: Can you post the full component? In the `onMapReady` part, what is `this.map` supposed to refer to?

Comment: This is the full component. And since I found no documentation on how to call get map boundaries I just looked for examples online and all of them used this.map so I assumed that was just how you do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code or run this Snack here: https://snack.expo.io/Cu5qYmcZm

```js
function Map() {
  const [mapRef, updateMapRef] = useState(null);
  const getBoundaries = () => {
    if (mapRef === null) {
      return;
    }
    mapRef
      .getMapBoundaries()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <MapView
        ref={(ref) => updateMapRef(ref)}
        onMapReady={() => getBoundaries()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You need to store the `ref` to the map, so you can refer back to it later (when you check the boundaries). You could also store this in the state. Then after the map is ready, the event is fired and using the ref we can refer back to it and query the info about the boundaries.

Comment: I think there's some context I'm not giving you, because I try to put this in and I get tons of errors and and things saying that its created but not read. Specifically with the this. declarations

Comment: Can you share the full code of where you are using this component? The Expo Snack runs without any errors.

Comment: ah okay yeah that's it, i'm not using expo. I'm using gradle. And sure here's the code, its too many characters to post so i just plopped it into carbon, got the png and posted it to imgur https://imgur.com/a/A7UZQSo

Comment: You are using a function component (not a class component) so you need to turn the above class component into a function component (you can use the `useState` to store the map ref)

Comment: okay so I've got it set up with usestate, and it returns fine when I log just mapRef, but whenever I log mapRef.getMapBoundaries(), it says that it's null

Comment: Take a look at the answer now - I have updated it to use hooks. `ref={(ref) => updateMapRef(ref)}` this is required on the map to update the ref in the state.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help